# Maximize JavaFX pane (HBox, for example)

Tags: javafx, eclipse-rcp

I have to rewrite existing app, with SWT.
I'm adding FXCanvas class with JavaFX components on it.
I noticed that somehow my panes (usually, HBox'es) do not change size when I maximize window, for example.

My code is:

```
final Display display = parent.getDisplay();
shell = new Shell(display);
Group group = new Group();
scene = new Scene(group, Color.rgb(shell.getBackground().getRed(), shell.getBackground().getGreen(),
shell.getBackground().getBlue()));

fxCanvas = new FXCanvas(shell, SWT.NONE) {
@Override
public Point computeSize(int wHint, int hHint, boolean changed) {
getScene().getWindow().sizeToScene();
int width = (int) getScene().getWidth();
int height = (int) getScene().getHeight();
return new Point(width, height);
}
};
fxCanvas.setScene(scene);

HBox hbox = new HBox();
hbox.setPadding(new Insets(15, 12, 15, 12));
hbox.setSpacing(20); // Gap between nodes
group.getChildren().add(hbox);
```

Please advise.

Comment: You are using a [Group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) as the parent of the HBox. Group takes the size of their children and is not resizable. You can either remove the group and directly use HBox as the root layout or use [Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) instead of Group.

Comment: Thanks for  your reply. But I tried both ways - doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Can you please recommend, what strategy should I choose if I have several Composit classes (panels), that call each other.. Parent creates child (one or two), they contain Label, ComboBox, etc. Should I create FXCanvas with HBox in the 'top' component, and then just pass links to HBox to children, so that they could operate with it,by calling hbox.getChildren().add(new Label()) ? I think, that's the problem, in my case. I have several components and I'm a bit lost in them.  Thanks.